# Retrieving a connection inside a page: PDO and PHP class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm new to classes and PDO as well. I'm trying to write a class with separate functions for connecting to the db and closing the connection so that, in a page, I can:

1. Open the connection with the `$db->connOpen`
2. Perform all the queries I need inside the page
3. Close the connection at the end of the script with `$db->connClose`

   ```
   class database
   {
       private $host       = '';
       private $db_name    = '';
       private $charset    = '';
       private $username   = '';
       private $password   = '';


       public function setHost($host) {
           $this->host = $host;
       }

       public function setDbName($db_name) {
           $this->db_name = $db_name;
       }

       public function setUser($username, $password) {
           $this->username = $username;
           $this->password = $password;
       }


       public function connOpen() {
           try {
               $dsn    = "mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->db_name;charset=$this->charset";
               $db     = new PDO($dsn, $this->username, $this->password, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
               $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
           } catch (PDOException $e) {
               echo $e->getMessage();
           }
       }

       public function connClose() {
           $db = null;
       }
   }
   ```

I guess the problem is regarding more the classes syntax than the PDO, since to fire a query like the one below into the page I would need to instantiate again the class `PDO`, doubling the connection to the db.

```
$stmt = $dbo->prepare('SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=:id');
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
$res  = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

My questions are:

1. How can achieve what I want using a class like the one above?
2. Is it correct, in this case, using a *persistent connection*?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, most people who wants to learn OOP starts with a database wrapper that implements singleton and interferes with error handling.

My tip is that you treat the database connection as any other variable:

```
class Post {
    function getByUserId(PDO $connection, $user_id) {
    }
}

$database = new PDO(...);
$post->getByUserId($database, 123);
```

This is called dependency injection.

And don't waste time and energy writing code to avoid useful features, such as:

- Centralised error handling
- Being able to connect to more than one database

Only care about writing a database wrapper when you really have real features to add on top of PDO. I can think of:

- Convert dates to `DateTime` objects automatically
- Pass all queries to a logger
- Throw custom exceptions on interesting events, such as duplicate index violation

... and even then be extremely careful to not make PDO worse ;-)

Comment: I followed your suggestion treating the PDO connection as a variable, returning it from the `conn()` function, and it worked. Thanks for all other tips Álvaro!

Answer (score 1):

I am using this with one singlton class which give me db ojbect and then I am using that object to query in other classes;

```
    <?php
    class db{
    /*** Declare instance ***/
    private static $instance = NULL;
    /**
     *
     * the constructor is set to private so
     * so nobody can create a new instance using new
     *
     */
    private function __construct() {
        /*** maybe set the db name here later ***/
    }
    /**
     *
     * Return DB instance or create intitial connection
     *
     * @return object (PDO)
     *
     * @access public
     *
     */
    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!self::$instance)
        {
            self::$instance = new \PDO("mysql:host=".databaseHost.";dbname=".databaseName."", databaseUserName,databasePassword);;
            self::$instance-> setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            self::$instance-> setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
    /**
     *
     * Like the constructor, we make __clone private
     * so nobody can clone the instance
     *
     */
    private function __clone(){
    }
} /*** end of class ***/
?>
```

class where  i am querying using db object

```
<?php
class posts {

    public function getPostOfUserId($userId,$offset=0,$limit=NULL){
        $helperString=" ";
        if(!empty($limit))
            $helperString=" LIMIT $offset, $limit ";
        $executor= db::getInstance()->prepare("SELECT posts.*,users.facebook_id, users.first_name as post_by FROM posts JOIN tagged_friends ON posts.id = tagged_friends.post_id JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id WHERE tagged_friends.user_id = :user_id ORDER BY posts.id DESC ".$helperString, array(\PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => \PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
        $executor->execute(array(':user_id'=>$userId));
        $posts=$executor->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if(!empty($posts))
            return $posts;
        else
            return ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your class seems to be so well written! But I actually need to study a lot more about classes to fully understand it :\